# Django - Select same column from many tables

Tags: python, django

I have many models with the same column name, something like this example:

```
class Model1(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_lenght=50)
    other_field = ....

class Model2(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_lenght=50)
    other_different_field = ....

class Model3(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_lenght=50)
    different_field = ....
```

I need to retrieve all names(`name` column) from those tables (Models) in one Django-sintax query. I have only one filter (`name__startswith='bla'`)

Is it possible?

If not, what is the easiest way to get this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is unnecessary and impossible to do in one query, but if you really want to get it fast:

```
result = []
for model in [Model1, Model2, Model3]:
    names = model.objects.filter(name__startswith='bla') \
                         .values_list('name', flat=True).distinct()
    result += names
```

This would hit database as many times as the amount of models you have(in this case it's three).

Comment: This is exactly what I need...simple and effective, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This Models are not related each other, you need to query them indivually:

```
Model1.objects.filter(name__startswith='bla')
Model2.objects.filter(name__startswith='bla')
Model3.objects.filter(name__startswith='bla')
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really need this, you can use something like this:

```
from django.db.models.loading import get_model

names = []
models = [('core','Model1'), ('core','Model2'), ('core','Model3')]
klasses = [get_model(app, model) for app, model in models]

for klass in klasses:
    for obj in klass.objects.filter(name__startswith='bla'):
        names.append(obj.name)
```

Of course this will hit the database more than once.
You can specify the models directly, like @Shang Wang says:

```
klasses = [Model1, Model2, Model3]
```

But if you need, something more complex, maybe the **get_model**, can be helpful.